# Where can I safely store my items in Fallout 1?

Tags: fallout

Where can I safely store my items in Fallout 1? I have lots of stimpacks, ammunation and weapons but I can't carry all of it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All containers are safe. However, if you want your items to be accesible on the go, you can use your follower as a pack mule. Just steal from them when you want to retrieve your items, but be careful no other NPCs see you!

Comment: That is a good approach but, what if my followers get killed? I'm looking for another way, like a safe house or a place where I can store the items without worrying about the container getting reseted.

Comment: I've improved my answer. It seems that all containers are safe.